# Leaflet .js unauthorized 401

Tags: leaflet

I am new to leaflet.js library, I am trying to build an application that display the geolocation of the user.

The problem is that even though I am using the default public token which is necessary to display the map. The console doesn't allow me to diplay the map and it returns a 401 unathorized type error, therefore the map only displays a grey screen and the pointer with the geolocation message but not the map, I have then try to use another token as well as other accounts but the result is the same, this is something that has never happened to me before.

````
L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={pk.eyJ1IjoiYXJ0aHVyOSIsImEiOiJja2cyZmVhZmUwMGFvMzBxcTJhYWp4bWtjIn0.nbrXeQG5fXBg5IFSN_XklQ}', {
 attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
 maxZoom: 18,
 id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
 tileSize: 512,
 zoomOffset: -1,
 accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoiYXJ0aHVyOSIsImEiOiJja2cyZmVhZmUwMGFvMzBxcTJhYWp4bWtjIn0.nbrXeQG5fXBg5IFSN_XklQ'
}).addTo(mymap);

mymap.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 16});

function onLocationFound(e) {
 var radius = e.accuracy;

 L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(mymap)
     .bindPopup("You are within " + radius + " meters from this point").openPopup();

 L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(mymap);
}

mymap.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);

function onLocationError(e) {
 alert(e.message);
}

mymap.on('locationerror', onLocationError);```
````

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with my api key and then it is working. Something with your key is wrong.

Also be sure that you replace the correct key, because you have one in the url directly and one in the options.

I suggest to replace your tile coe with this and try another key:

```
L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: '© <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/about/maps/">Mapbox</a> © <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> <strong><a href="https://www.mapbox.com/map-feedback/" target="_blank">Improve this map</a></strong>',
    tileSize: 512,
    maxZoom: 18,
    zoomOffset: -1,
    id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
    accessToken: 'YOUR_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN'
}).addTo(mymap);
```

Comment: Still not working, nor with your code or with the other API keys.